# Change a value in a cell using a checkbox

Tags: excel, checkbox, excel-2007, cell, worksheet-function

What I'm doing is based on [Change a value in a cell from a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989175/change-a-value-in-a-cell-from-a-checkbox).

My problem is that on checking the tick box while using:

```
=IF(C23=TRUE,B3+1,B3)
```

will add the value, but unchecking the box won't return the cell to it's previous value.
If checked it should display `1` and if unchecked `-1`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Didn't get your problem? Why 2 and -2? Can you explain it in detail.

Comment: +2 and -2 are just an example, If I click on the tick box, it will change the value from say 0 to 2, when I untick it, the value stays the same, I click it again and now the value is 4, I would like it to be 2 when clicked, 0 when not clicked.

Comment: When unchecked, why don't you subtract the value? Like B3-1 in the else part of IF condition.

Comment: I don't know how to do that :) I've goggled around, they always seem to be on multiple lines, which I can't seem to do in excel.

Comment: Maybe this shows what I'm trying to do better "=IF(Q1=TRUE,R1+1,R1) =IF(Q1=FALSE,R1-1,R1)" Trying to +1 when it's ticked, -1 when it's unticked, but it only ever displays FALSE for some reason.

Comment: Why did you post the same title as another question which you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instead:

```
=2*C23-1
```

Comment: ok, I put that in numerous cell's, nothing happened when I checked and unchecked the box.

Comment: Automatic Calculation is on.